# Using variables in MySQL command with Dapper C#

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

Im trying to use MySQL select command with 2 variables in c# but It only works with one variable.

My goal is to create a login system which uses a MySQL table with 3 columns: UserName , Password and TableName.
Then I want to go to another table (with TableName as the table name) and in that table there is information about people which I display in WPF ListBox.

```
return connection.Query<Person>($"select * from "+ TableName +" where PhoneNumber LIKE "+ searchData and id > 0 order by Name").ToList();
```

I use this code to search the list by phone number.

TableName and searchData are the variables.

This is my code which doesnt work.

Comment: And you shouldn't write an sql command in that way. Dapper has full support for parameters. Dapper couldn't save you from Sql Injection if you write your query like that.

Comment: Try this http://dapper-tutorial.net/parameter-list

Comment: The above code doesn't compile. There is an odd number of `"` characters @Americano.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't parameterized *at all*; parameters are specific SQL concepts, so you might have:

```
return connection.Query<Person>(
 $"select * from {TableName} where PhoneNumber LIKE @searchData and id > 0 order by Name",
 new { searchData  }).AsList();
```

(or `:searchData`, etc, depending on the variant of SQL)

This parameterizes the `searchData` correctly.

Note, however, that table names **cannot** be parameterized; in general you should avoid *needing* to inject a table name into SQL, but when you need to do this, you will have to concatenate it much like you are already. It would be advisable to white-list the table name since you cannot prevent it being a SQL injection hole.